# json_encode not working in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

This block of code json_encode line echo nothing

```
    include "connect.php";
$sql="select * from customers"; 


$arr = array();
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $firstname = $row['firstname']; 
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];
    $arr[] = array('lastname' => $lastname, 'lastname' => $lastname);

}

echo json_encode($arr);// results in nothing.
```

What am i doing wrong? Help please

Comment: Sounds like the array is empty. If you `var_dump()` the array before encoding it, it will likely be empty. You probably need to check for sql errors.

Comment: Shouldn't one of the keys in `$arr` array be 'firstname' ?

Comment: Almost certain your array is empty.please var_dump the array

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do `echo json_encode($arr);` on an empty array you should see the result `[]`. So the issue is probably somewhere in the mysqli_ code.

Please check that status of all calls made via any of the mysql database extensions. This way you are informed when you make some sort of error.

```
include "connect.php";

// this should probably go in the 'connect.php'
// this is just an example no a difinitive piece of code
function db_err(&$conn, &$sql, $lineNo)
{
    if ( $conn_errno($conn) ) {
        echo sprinf( 'Query %s failed on line %d Code:%d Message:%s', 
                      $sql, 
                      $lineNo,
                      mylsqi_errno($conn), 
                      mylsqi_error($conn));
        exit;
    }
}

$sql="select * from customers"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
db_err($conn,$sql, __LINE__);

$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $firstname = $row['firstname']; 
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];
    $arr[] = array('lastname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname);

}

echo json_encode($arr);
```